# How can I set a variable to one of two random options?

Tags: javascript, random

I know how to get a random number with Javascript, but I do not know how to set a variable to text randomly. I want it to randomly choose between saying one thing and another thing. I realize that this is probably a fairly basic question, but I can't find any tutorials online on it.

Comment: `thingsToSay = ["one thing", "another thing"]; say = thingsToSay[randomNumberBetween0and1];`

Comment: you could have an array with the two options, e.g. `const opts = ['opt1', 'opt2']`, and randomly select it with `opts[Math.round(Math.random())]`

Comment: You don't need a tutorial. How would you do it without a computer involved at all? Like, if you had two pieces of paper with different things written on them, how would you choose a random one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array with the two options for text:

```
var array = ["hello", "world"];
```

Then you will choose random index of the array as follow:

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
```

Now you can just get random chosen text (between the texts in the array) by the random index:

```
var chosenText = array[index];
```

Notice that this would work no matter what the length of the array would be.

Try to run it:

```js
var array = ["hello", "world"];
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
var chosenText = array[index];
console.log(chosenText);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random()` generates an number between `0` and `1`. You can check if its greater than `0.5` then return `thing1` otherwise `thing2`. Both results will have `50%` chance.

```js
const res = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "thing1" : "thing2"
console.log(res)
```

Another way is create an array and use `Math.round()` on random float value and use it as index of array.

```js
const things = ["thing1","thing2"];
let res = things[Math.round(Math.random())]
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to create an array of the 2 strings, and then select the index by creating a random number between 1 and 2 ( or 0 and 1 );

```
const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2); // generates a random number
const arr = ["String One", "String Two"]; // create array of strings
const randomString = arr[num]; // select string with index of random number
```